# How to add one CSS attribute to an element while it should not be implemented on its child elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, web-frontend

`<a href=" ..." title="..." rel="home" class="navbar-brand"> <img src="..." alt="..." class="img-fluid d-inline-block align-top" /> sth is written here </a>`
I have the above HTML code and I want to make the element "a" disappeared when @media (max-width: 767px) while element "img" inside it should appear, and I can only change the CSS code, does anyone know how I can do this ??